# External access web page with VirtualHosts and Wampserver

Tags: virtualhost, wampserver

I am a newbie in wampserver.

I installed it and I can acesss web pages with localhost port 8000 without problems. Yes, I changed default port to 8000 and all works well with localhost.

Now, I created a simple project web page and I need external access. Here is my settings:
But I get the next error when I try to acesss remotely:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at agenda.myvnc.com Port 8000
//agenda.myvnc.com is my elastic IP host server
```

My sample project:

```
Folders:
c:\wamp64\www
...........cloudappoint.myvnc.com(subfolder in www)

File in cloudappoint.myvnc.com folder:  index.php
```

NOIP DNS:

```
- Host:cloudappoint.myvnc.com       
- Target IP:XXX.XXX.XXX:8000(My host is located at amazon ec2 with elastic ip- XXXX.XXX.XXX)
- type:URL
```

WampServer VirtualHosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName cloudappoint.myvnc.com
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/cloudappoint.myvnc.com
    ErrorLog "logs/agenda-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/agenda-access.log" common
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/cloudappoint.myvnc.com">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

EDITED: Here is my complete Virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName cloudappoint
    ServerAlias cloudappoint.myvnc.com
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/webagenda
    ErrorLog "logs/agenda-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/agenda-access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am unable to acesss remotely cloudappoint.myvnc.com, but if I move

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda/">
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

out from VirtualHost, all works well. Then, I guess 3.06 has broken Directory into Virtual Hosts.

Comment: Have you Port Forwarded your Router? See https://portforward.com/ for help with that

Comment: There is no need. My server is on Amazon EC2. I can log remotely if I do grant   Require all granted to localhost. But I can´t do it for security reasons.

Comment: It seems something was broken with directories into virtual hosts in Wamp 3.06

Comment: Then use `Require local` and on the next line `Require ip <your_ip>`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood. My site wiil be a public site. Why do I have to hard code my IP? This is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited the question with my complete Virtual Hosts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP 3.06, is Directory into Virtual Hosts broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824268/wamp-3-06-is-directory-into-virtual-hosts-broken)