# WAMP 3.06, is Directory into Virtual Hosts broken?

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I  am  using WAMP 3.06. I have a web site hosted in "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda"

When I try to access the site remotely using "http://cloudappoint.myvnc.com", I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /webagenda on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at agenda.myvnc.com Port 8000
```

My virtual host file is:

```
# Virtual Hosts

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#if I uncomment the next lines the problem is over
#<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda">
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
#DirectoryIndex index.php
#AllowOverride None
#Require all granted
#</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName cloudappoint
    ServerAlias cloudappoint.myvnc.com
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/webagenda
    ErrorLog "logs/agenda-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/agenda-access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see from my comments, if I I uncomment the next lines the problem is over:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What is wrong here, please?

Answer (score -1):

If moving the `<Directory>` block out of the `<VirtualHost>` block causes access to be allowed then it is a fair assumption that there is something wrong with the `<VirtualHost>` definition.

Can I suggest that you try this change in your definition

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

    ServerName cloudappoint.myvnc.com           <--change
    ServerAlias www.cloudappoint.myvnc.com      <--change

    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/webagenda
    ErrorLog "logs/agenda-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/agenda-access.log" common
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/webagenda/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

I assume you are adding the non standard port number to the url when trying to access the site?

```
http://cloudappoint.myvnc.com:8000
```

When I add the :8000 I do not get the error I get an offline page saying

```
The site you have requested is currently unavailable, 
please try back again later.
```

Comment: Maybe you are forgetting to add the port number to the URL `:8000`